# Kendo UI Mobile - CSS attribute resets on view transition when removed in JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

Currently I am handling the flicker of unstyled content of my kendo mobile web app by applying the following css rule within my css file:

```
[data-role="content"]
    { 
    visibility: hidden;
    }
```

This hides all of my content within my kendo views, then in the JQuery "load" event, I remove the above css attribute:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    // flicker of unstyled content
    $("[data-role=\"content\"]").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

All has worked fine and I haven't had any issues with this, except when using kendo's view transitions.

When I use the `slide:left` transition, the original `visibility: hidden;` defined in my css file is re-applied, causing everything to be invisible.

Is there a reason why this is happening, specifically, with kendo and how it handles views and transitions? I understand I could probably manually add a class with `visibility: hidden;` to each `data-role="content"` element, and then remove that class in jquery's "load" event handler, but I wanted to my solution to be a bit less "hardcoded."

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this message has been upvoted recently, I will supply the way I handle the Flicker of unstyled content. It hasn't failed me..

1.) Add a class to the main page of your single page application:

```
<style>
    .m-hide-unstyled-content {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

2.) Create a global function in the main page of your single page application:

```
<script>
        function removeFlickerOfUnstyledContentClass() {
            // flicker of unstyled content fix
            $(".m-hide-unstyled-content).removeClass("m-hide-unstyled-content");
        }
</script>
```

3.) For every view, make sure to manually add the `data-role="content"` div tag, while applying the class we created above:

```
<div class="m-hide-unstyled-content" data-role="content">
    ...
</div>
```

4.) Finally, call the function we created in step 2 at the end of every view's `data-init` function:

```
<div data-role="view" data-init="initMyView">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    function initMyView(event) {
        ...
        removeFlickerOfUnstyledContentClass();
    }
</script>
```

Using this setup, you will never encounter those nasty flickers of unstyled content! Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 0):

The data-role=content attributes are set when the view is initialised - so your load event handler won't be affect all views (unless you have data-role=content set manually).

You may consider hiding the application container instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @underlog. I actually am adding the data-role=content manually to all my views. also, hiding the application container will generate an error that says Kendo cannot find any views. That's why I am going this route..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the flicker by setting display:none to the elements that flicker. Then use CSS or JS to display them as necessary. Perhaps onHide or onShow.